# Finding Number of Elements on Page (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simply count the number of `<li>` elements I have.

I am wrote this:

```
<script>
    var n = $("li").length;
    alert(n);
</script>
```

But for some reason I am getting this error in the console instead of an alert with the number of `<li>` elements:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null filter:297
(anonymous function)`

Comment: where is your jQuery script include?

Comment: Can you replicate this in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either move your script to the bottom of the page , just before the `HTML` ends or encase that in `DOM Ready handler` . Also it is a better idead to include jQuery from a CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
     $(function() {
        var n = $("li").length;
        alert(n);
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: If `$("li").length` doesn't work, how would `$(function(){})` work at the same place in the code?

Comment: If `$("li").length` doesn't work probably because the DOm was not loaded when the OP'as script ran

Comment: If the DOM was not loaded, `$()` will still return an object with `length` property set to `0`.

Comment: You're all right. I had jquery included fine - but the version must be deprecated somehow. The `ajax.googleapis.com` include made everything better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include the code in `$( document ).ready`

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/Dk5XH/1/)</kbd>

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var n = $("li").length;
  alert(n);
});
```